# Impossibly fast delegate in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

[This legendary C++ delegate article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates) can be easily converted into C++11, without the need for fancy preprocessor magic in the original. I'd like to know if I got all the necessary C++11 nuances right. Suggestions?

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DELEGATE_HPP
# define DELEGATE_HPP

#include <cassert>

#include <memory>

#include <new>

#include <type_traits>

#include <utility>

template <typename T> class delegate;

template<class R, class ...A>
class delegate<R (A...)>
{
  using stub_ptr_type = R (*)(void*, A&&...);

  delegate(void* const o, stub_ptr_type const m) noexcept :
    object_ptr_(o),
    stub_ptr_(m)
  {
  }

public:
  delegate() = default;

  delegate(delegate const&) = default;

  delegate(delegate&&) = default;

  delegate(::std::nullptr_t const) noexcept : delegate() { }

  template <class C, typename =
    typename ::std::enable_if< ::std::is_class<C>{}>::type>
  explicit delegate(C const* const o) noexcept :
    object_ptr_(const_cast<C*>(o))
  {
  }

  template <class C, typename =
    typename ::std::enable_if< ::std::is_class<C>{}>::type>
  explicit delegate(C const& o) noexcept :
    object_ptr_(const_cast<C*>(&o))
  {
  }

  template <class C>
  delegate(C* const object_ptr, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...))
  {
    *this = from(object_ptr, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  delegate(C* const object_ptr, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const)
  {
    *this = from(object_ptr, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  delegate(C& object, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...))
  {
    *this = from(object, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  delegate(C const& object, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const)
  {
    *this = from(object, method_ptr);
  }

  template <
    typename T,
    typename = typename ::std::enable_if<
      !::std::is_same<delegate, typename ::std::decay<T>::type>{}
    >::type
  >
  delegate(T&& f) :
    store_(operator new(sizeof(typename ::std::decay<T>::type)),
      functor_deleter<typename ::std::decay<T>::type>),
    store_size_(sizeof(typename ::std::decay<T>::type))
  {
    using functor_type = typename ::std::decay<T>::type;

    new (store_.get()) functor_type(::std::forward<T>(f));

    object_ptr_ = store_.get();

    stub_ptr_ = functor_stub<functor_type>;

    deleter_ = deleter_stub<functor_type>;
  }

  delegate& operator=(delegate const&) = default;

  delegate& operator=(delegate&&) = default;

  template <class C>
  delegate& operator=(R (C::* const rhs)(A...))
  {
    return *this = from(static_cast<C*>(object_ptr_), rhs);
  }

  template <class C>
  delegate& operator=(R (C::* const rhs)(A...) const)
  {
    return *this = from(static_cast<C const*>(object_ptr_), rhs);
  }

  template <
    typename T,
    typename = typename ::std::enable_if<
      !::std::is_same<delegate, typename ::std::decay<T>::type>{}
    >::type
  >
  delegate& operator=(T&& f)
  {
    using functor_type = typename ::std::decay<T>::type;

    if ((sizeof(functor_type) > store_size_) || !store_.unique())
    {
      store_.reset(operator new(sizeof(functor_type)),
        functor_deleter<functor_type>);

      store_size_ = sizeof(functor_type);
    }
    else
    {
      deleter_(store_.get());
    }

    new (store_.get()) functor_type(::std::forward<T>(f));

    object_ptr_ = store_.get();

    stub_ptr_ = functor_stub<functor_type>;

    deleter_ = deleter_stub<functor_type>;

    return *this;
  }

  template <R (* const function_ptr)(A...)>
  static delegate from() noexcept
  {
    return { nullptr, function_stub<function_ptr> };
  }

  template <class C, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...)>
  static delegate from(C* const object_ptr) noexcept
  {
    return { object_ptr, method_stub<C, method_ptr> };
  }

  template <class C, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const>
  static delegate from(C const* const object_ptr) noexcept
  {
    return { const_cast<C*>(object_ptr), const_method_stub<C, method_ptr> };
  }

  template <class C, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...)>
  static delegate from(C& object) noexcept
  {
    return { &object, method_stub<C, method_ptr> };
  }

  template <class C, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const>
  static delegate from(C const& object) noexcept
  {
    return { const_cast<C*>(&object), const_method_stub<C, method_ptr> };
  }

  template <typename T>
  static delegate from(T&& f)
  {
    return ::std::forward<T>(f);
  }

  static delegate from(R (* const function_ptr)(A...))
  {
    return function_ptr;
  }

  template <class C>
  using member_pair =
    ::std::pair<C* const, R (C::* const)(A...)>;

  template <class C>
  using const_member_pair =
    ::std::pair<C const* const, R (C::* const)(A...) const>;

  template <class C>
  static delegate from(C* const object_ptr,
    R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...))
  {
    return member_pair<C>(object_ptr, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  static delegate from(C const* const object_ptr,
    R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const)
  {
    return const_member_pair<C>(object_ptr, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  static delegate from(C& object, R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...))
  {
    return member_pair<C>(&object, method_ptr);
  }

  template <class C>
  static delegate from(C const& object,
    R (C::* const method_ptr)(A...) const)
  {
    return const_member_pair<C>(&object, method_ptr);
  }

  void reset() { stub_ptr_ = nullptr; store_.reset(); }

  void reset_stub() noexcept { stub_ptr_ = nullptr; }

  void swap(delegate& other) noexcept { ::std::swap(*this, other); }

  bool operator==(delegate const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return (object_ptr_ == rhs.object_ptr_) && (stub_ptr_ == rhs.stub_ptr_);
  }

  bool operator!=(delegate const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return !operator==(rhs);
  }

  bool operator<(delegate const& rhs) const noexcept
  {
    return (object_ptr_ < rhs.object_ptr_) ||
      ((object_ptr_ == rhs.object_ptr_) && (stub_ptr_ < rhs.stub_ptr_));
  }

  bool operator==(::std::nullptr_t const) const noexcept
  {
    return !stub_ptr_;
  }

  bool operator!=(::std::nullptr_t const) const noexcept
  {
    return stub_ptr_;
  }

  explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return stub_ptr_; }

  R operator()(A... args) const
  {
//  assert(stub_ptr);
    return stub_ptr_(object_ptr_, ::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

private:
  friend struct ::std::hash<delegate>;

  using deleter_type = void (*)(void*);

  void* object_ptr_;
  stub_ptr_type stub_ptr_{};

  deleter_type deleter_;

  ::std::shared_ptr<void> store_;
  ::std::size_t store_size_;

  template <class T>
  static void functor_deleter(void* const p)
  {
    static_cast<T*>(p)->~T();

    operator delete(p);
  }

  template <class T>
  static void deleter_stub(void* const p)
  {
    static_cast<T*>(p)->~T();
  }

  template <R (*function_ptr)(A...)>
  static R function_stub(void* const, A&&... args)
  {
    return function_ptr(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <class C, R (C::*method_ptr)(A...)>
  static R method_stub(void* const object_ptr, A&&... args)
  {
    return (static_cast<C*>(object_ptr)->*method_ptr)(
      ::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <class C, R (C::*method_ptr)(A...) const>
  static R const_method_stub(void* const object_ptr, A&&... args)
  {
    return (static_cast<C const*>(object_ptr)->*method_ptr)(
      ::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <typename>
  struct is_member_pair : std::false_type { };

  template <class C>
  struct is_member_pair< ::std::pair<C* const,
    R (C::* const)(A...)> > : std::true_type
  {
  };

  template <typename>
  struct is_const_member_pair : std::false_type { };

  template <class C>
  struct is_const_member_pair< ::std::pair<C const* const,
    R (C::* const)(A...) const> > : std::true_type
  {
  };

  template <typename T>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    !(is_member_pair<T>{} ||
    is_const_member_pair<T>{}),
    R
  >::type
  functor_stub(void* const object_ptr, A&&... args)
  {
    return (*static_cast<T*>(object_ptr))(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <typename T>
  static typename ::std::enable_if<
    is_member_pair<T>{} ||
    is_const_member_pair<T>{},
    R
  >::type
  functor_stub(void* const object_ptr, A&&... args)
  {
    return (static_cast<T*>(object_ptr)->first->*
      static_cast<T*>(object_ptr)->second)(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }
};

namespace std
{
  template <typename R, typename ...A>
  struct hash<::delegate<R (A...)> >
  {
    size_t operator()(::delegate<R (A...)> const& d) const noexcept
    {
      auto const seed(hash<void*>()(d.object_ptr_));

      return hash<typename ::delegate<R (A...)>::stub_ptr_type>()(
        d.stub_ptr_) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }
  };
}

#endif // DELEGATE_HPP
```

Example use:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "delegate.hpp"

struct A
{
  void foo(int a)
  {
    std::cout << "method got: " << a << std::endl;
  }
};

void foo(int a)
{
  std::cout << "function got: " << a << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  auto d1(delegate<void (int)>::from<foo>());

  A a;
  auto d2(delegate<void (int)>::from<A, &A::foo>(&a));
  auto d3(delegate<void (int)>{foo});
  auto d4(delegate<void (int)>(&a, &A::foo));

  d1(1);
  d2(2);
  d3(3);
  d4(4);

  int b(2);

  auto dx(delegate<void ()>(
    [b](){std::cout << "hello world: " << b << std::endl;}));

  dx();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for using this instead of `std::function`?

Comment: @ony It is usually faster, especially when using pointer to member template parameters.

Comment: is there any reason to have slower implementation of `std::function` in C++ lib/run-time? As well there is code `return from([object, method_ptr](A const... args){ return (object.*method_ptr)(args...); }); }`

Comment: @ony Benchmark and you'll see. If you like it, use it. Is there something wrong with the code? Does it fail to compile? If so, please post compile error. The code is C++11. You can also post a critique as an answer.

Comment: Last time I checked `std::function` is quite fast compared to the impossibly fast delegate class. I did this benchmark by using my [library](https://github.com/miguelishawt/Wink-Signals) awhile ago with Apple clang 4.1 (although the benchmark for std::function isn't actually there, I'm sure you could test it out yourself using your own code or even mine).

Comment: @miguel.martin Thanks, I don't really present the class here as some kind of holy grail delegate, but want to gather comments on the C++11 style I use. In my compiler setup `std::function` is about 10x slower than the impossibly fast delegate (when using template function pointer parameters).

Comment: Hey, I'd like to use this in one of my project. Is this the definitive version or have you improved it further?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Hope it's going to work for you. I don't know, if this is the best solution.

Comment: @user1095108: check my answer below - so far so good

Comment: Hi, can you please explain a bit how you came up with your hash function for this?

Comment: @bjackfly It comes from `boost`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471691/good-hash-function-for-pair-of-primitive-types

Comment: @user1095108 You said *"In my compiler setup, `std::function` is about 10x slower..."*. What compiler/library is that? I've spent hours trying to beat gcc's libstdc++ implementation and everything I tried was exactly the same speed as `std::function`.

Comment: @doug65536 That's the beauty of open-source development. What I wrote was true at the time, but it may not be anymore. Both `g++` and `libstdc++` change over time. You can use `::std::function`, if you think it is better than this delegate. I've had bad experiences with it, when doing some `OpenGL` programming. It showed high in the profiler output and so I've looked around for alternatives. In hindsight, I should not have bothered with it, though the subject is fascinating and has a long history.

Comment: @user1095108 If you were using MSVC, I remember a bug on [microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com) complaining of an unbelievably slow `std::function` implementation. I tried to find it to quote the link, but it seems they purge old bugs or their search is really badly implemented (like their `std::function` implementation ;). Something like "std::function copies the object more than 10x".

Comment: @user1095108 [Here it is](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/649268).

Comment: The repeated, and ongoing edits to this question have completely invalidated the existing answers. This question has turned in to a mess of revisions, interleaved history, and is a very poor example of how Code Review questions should be managed. See [Can I edit my own question to include revised code? Also, how to handle iterative reviews?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/can-i-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-code-also-how-to-handle-iterativ)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks by and large OK. Just some nitpicks

- the default constructor could just be `delegate() = default;`, or otherwise initialize *all* members... or remove it entirely if it makes no sense.
- the copy constructor should use initialization, not assignment.
- `swap` should return `void`.
- Assignment should pass-by-value:

  ```
  delegate& operator=(delegate rhs) { rhs.swap(*this); return *this; }
  ```
- Invocation should use arbitrary arguments and forwarding:

  ```
  template <typename ...B>
  R operator()(B &&... b)
  {
      return (*stub_ptr)(object_ptr, std::forward<B>(b)...);
  }
  ```

  In fact, you should add `enable_if` with some variadic version of `is_constructible<A, B>...` to the operator so you don't create impossible overloads.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I think the forwarding is still shaky, as the static function stubs still make copies of their arguments. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @user1095108: I thought the invocation was `auto d = delegate::from_function<foo>();` -- there's no room for arguments, is there?

Comment: What about lambdas? Can we turn them into delegates?

Comment: @WarrenSeine I've added lambda support.

Comment: Why should assignment pass by value?

Comment: @doug65536 to avoid having to have `const T&` and `T&&` versions of assignment; passing by value will choose move construction or copy construction automatically for `rhs`.

Answer (score 4):

I love this! Ran some quick benchmarks:

```
int x{0}; 
for(int xx = 0; xx < 5; ++xx)
{
    startBenchmark();
    {
        std::function<int(int)> t2 = [&x](int i){ return i + x; };
        std::function<void(int)> t1 = [&x, &t2](int i){ x = t2(i); };
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) t1(i);
    } lo << lt("std::func") << endBenchmark() << endl;

    startBenchmark();
    {
        delegate<int(int)> t2 = [&x](int i){ return i + x; };
        delegate<void(int)> t1 = [&x, &t2](int i){ x = t2(i); };
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) t1(i);
    } lo << lt("ssvu::fastfunc") << endBenchmark() << endl;
}
```

Results:

```
[std::func]                           3278 ms
[ssvu::fastfunc]                      2147 ms
[std::func]                           3264 ms
[ssvu::fastfunc]                      2126 ms
[std::func]                           3302 ms
[ssvu::fastfunc]                      2182 ms
[std::func]                           3306 ms
[ssvu::fastfunc]                      2135 ms
...
```

Your `delegate` class is always faster by 1 seconds, even in this naive benchmark.

---

**Actual review:**

I tested changing all `std::function<R(A...)>` to your `delegate<R(A...)>` in *all of my projects*.

After making a small adjustment to the `delegate` code, **everything works** as expected!

In some of my code I used to do this:

```
void a(std::function<void()> mMaybe = nullptr)
{
    // do something
    if(mMaybe != nullptr) mMaybe();
}
```

This code broke when using `delegate` instead of `std::function`. I fixed it by adding these lines to your `delegate` class:

```
delegate(std::nullptr_t) : object_ptr_{nullptr}, stub_ptr_{nullptr} { }
bool operator==(std::nullptr_t) const noexcept      { return object_ptr_ == nullptr; }
bool operator!=(std::nullptr_t) const noexcept      { return object_ptr_ != nullptr; }
```

Now the above code compiles and works correctly. With this small adjustment, the `delegate` class is a **probably faster drop-in replacement** for `std::function`.

Comment: I'll add your code to the `delegate` class, thanks for the contribution.

Comment: Try the `staticdelegate.hpp` from the repository as well, please.

Comment: @user1095108: http://pastebin.com/YwEaLhhF

Comment: Note: *rawfunc* is `delegate<int(int&, int)> t1 = &rawFunc;`, with `rawFunc` being a simple global function. 

Note 2: if you manage to optimize *rawfunc*, *mem rawfunc* can be optimized using the same concepts behind Don's fastdelegate (binding it as if it was a global function).

Comment: Note 3: [I greatly cleaned up my Don's fastdelegate implementation](https://gist.github.com/SuperV1234/6455139), if you want to see how it handles raw global functions

Comment: `g++` gives greatly different results, with same compiler options: http://pastebin.com/UxDfd0rE

Comment: @user1095108: I'll try in a while and report :) consider making it automatically use `from<rawFunc>()` when constructing like this, though: `delegate<int(int&, int)> = &rawFunc;`

Comment: Can't. See that `rawFunc` is a template parameter? It is a compile-time thing. Basically, it is a faster way to achieve the same thing as Don's delegate without `reinterpret_cast`s

Comment: staticdelegate is making use of shady tricks, add `static_new` to Don's delegate and revel in the speed. `static_new` is a fast alternative to the `::std::shared_ptr<void>` trick.

Comment: @user1095108: http://pastebin.com/EC7jn3b4 - there may be something wrong with my `g++` installation, but I'm not sure; I think it may just be the optimizer sucking at unrolling the giant loops

Comment: Also, I implemented your `static_storage` in my `FastFunc` implementation, but no performance gains - strange

Comment: Ah well, never mind then.

Comment: The fact is that I'm benchmarking only the calls (`operator()`) - I guess the bottleneck is somewhere else in my code, not the `operator new`.

Comment: Would you mind deleting your 2 answers? We polluted the page quite a bit :) I still think btw, that for calls of raw functions and member functions your are instantiating the delegate incorrectly. You need to do `delegate<..sig..>::from<rawfunc>()`. Note, the pointer to function is a template parameter. Don't put the pointer between ().

Comment: Also, I've updated the staticdelegate once more. Get it from the repository.

Comment: I found a cool SFINAE trick to save some memory (and an allocation): check if a functor/lambda is trivial (can be constructed like a global function pointer) at compile time. If it is, store it's address in a simple `void*` instead of allocating. http://pastie.org/8304603

Comment: Actually, there's no need for storage at all in that case.

Comment: This is what I am trying to tell you for several days now, Yeah, no storage is needed, you're instantiating the delegate wrongly. You need to pass the pointers as template parameters and as a reward you don't need the ugly `reinterpret_cast`s in the code. Runtime pointers are provided for people who don't care about performance. Anyway I've made slight improvements, as far as handling raw functions is concerned, but probably nothing substantial :)

Comment: @user1095108: new benchies http://pastie.org/8305796

Answer (score 0):

Problematic results:

```
[std::func]                           31855 ms
[ssvu::fastfunc]                      123848 ms
```

Benchmark code:

```
int x{0};
for(int xx = 0; xx < 5; ++xx)
{
    startBenchmark();
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
        {
            std::function<int(int)> t2 = t2impl;
            std::function<void(int)> t1 = [&x, &t2](int i){ x = t2(i); };
            t1(i);
        }
    } lo << lt("std::func") << endBenchmark() << endl;
    startBenchmark();
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
        {
            FastFunc<int(int)> t2 = t2impl;
            FastFunc<void(int)> t1 = [&x, &t2](int i){ x = t2(i); };
            t1(i);
        }
    } lo << lt("ssvu::fastfunc") << endBenchmark() << endl;
}
```

`std::function` performed **way** better on this benchmark. Any idea why?

Comment: It probably has to do something with initialization of functors. `::std::function` supposedly optimizes initialization with small functors. I didn't optimize that use case. Try to move the definition of FastFunc objects outside of the loop, and then simply `std::move` the lambda object into it.

Comment: I did some profiling with valgrind (only for the `delegate` class): it seems the real bottleneck is dynamic memory allocation http://i.imgur.com/k01y9fA.png

Comment: Try to just assign in the loop: `t2 = std::move(t2impl); t1 = std::move([&x, &t2](int i){ x = t2(i); };);`

Comment: @user1095108 no dice - results are same to the original benchmark code (`delegate` is a lot slower than `std::function`)

Comment: If this is a frequent use-case in your code, you need to find some other delegate or optimize this code for it (i.e. instead of `new`-ing, you can use a small `char[]` array to store the functor - watch out for alignment issues) or you can try using `Boost.Pool` or some small object allocator. Note that the original delegate didn't support functors (lambda objects) at all, but exploited the possibility of compile-time pointer-to-function and pointer-to-function-member template parameters.

Comment: @user1095108: I tried allocating a `char` buffer and using placement new on it but hit a roadblock: I need to call the allocated `obj_ptr_` destructor before `delete[]`-ing the buffer, but I have no way of knowing what type `obj_ptr_` is. Also, I can't seem to understand how I may circumvent `shared_ptr` reference counting if two `delegate` objects can point to the same function. It would be great if you could show an example on how to do this, because I've been looking for a `C++11`-compliant fast delegate forever, and this one is very promising

Comment: You need to define 2 new function templates, say, `copier` and `mover`, similar to the existing `deleter` to move and copy the contained functors in the `char[]` array. Don't forget `alignof` and `std::align`.The more significant question to me is, whether placement `new` into a `char[]` is faster than into the heap? There is no other way to copy the lambda object, that is known to me. It shouldn't be significantly faster/slower. Did you really move the delegate instantiations out of the loop and assigned in the loop?

Comment: *"Did you move delegate instantiations out of the loop..."*: yes, but `std::function` is still a lot faster, even if I keep its initialization in the other loop. I've done some research and there is another way to store functors/memfn pointers: [Don Clugston's fastest possible delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible). There is a [C++11 implementation here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible?msg=4489700#xx4489700xx) but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: The idea, as far as I understand, is to use `reinterpret_cast` and some other tricks to *convert* any kind of function pointer into a global-like function pointer. [Someone managed to implement lambda expressions into it easily](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4609198/Support-for-Lambda-Expressions.aspx) but I don't understand the code well enough to attempt an implementation of its cast magic into your `delegate` class - I'm trying to, though. Maybe it could give you some ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Yes, write your own delegate, by all means :) I don't understand the other delegate too well, I wanted easily inline-able, easily understandable code in the current implementation. Without `reinterpret_cast`s.

Comment: Another improvement could be `FastFunc<int(int)> t2 = FastFunc<int(int)>::from<t2impl>();` if `t2impl` is a function.

Comment: Please check https://code.google.com/p/cpppractice/ for `arraydelegate`, but it only works with `gcc`.

Comment: @user1095108, thanks for the link. I use clang, and I was trying to get it to work, but `max_align_t` is probably not available on clang. Is there any suitable alternative?

Comment: for now, put in 8 instead of max_align_t. It doesn't work fast anyway. Next clang version will probably fix this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10467/discussion-between-vittorio-romeo-and-user1095108)